# executing bash shell from cshell (tcsh)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

I have an issue that should be simple but I just can't find the solution anywhere.

I am trying to do something as simple as setting and envvar in a bash script.
running the script from a bash terminal it works fine, but running it from tcsh which is default on the machine I am using I get unknown command when I try to export my variable.

here is my VERY simple script. my_tmp_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#clear
echo $$

echo "setting environment variables"
MY_TEMP_ENVVAR=123@tmp.com
export MY_TEMP_ENVVAR
echo $MY_TEMP_ENVVAR
```

if i source this I get

```
source my_tmp_script.sh
8790
setting environment variables
MY_TEMP_ENVVAR=123@tmp.com: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
```

if I change to bash shell, it works just fine.

what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: do you get unknown command when you execute ./my_tmp_script.sh or only when you source it. The execution should work, but the source should not, since it ignores the shell defined.

Comment: only when sourcing

Comment: Dario's answer below tells the reasons and solution for your problem.

Comment: well no, unless I am missing something it does not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourcing a script means current shell process execute script commands, whereas executing a script the shell spawns a new process and waits until it finishes (except if launched in background &) to get exit status ($?).

The interest is to modify current shell settings which cannot be done executing script.

Sourcing a bash script with tcsh shell is a nonsense because they are different languages, and bash settings may not be useful for tcsh shell.

The error shows tcsh cannot define and export environment variable

with bash

```
MY_TEMP_ENVVAR=123@tmp.com
export MY_TEMP_ENVVAR
```

with tcsh

```
setenv MY_TEMP_ENVVAR=123@tmp.com
```

another solution if possible is to change default shell or start bash at login, the shebang (!#/bin/bash) has no effect when sourcing a script file.

Comment: I think your answer tells me to go for a different solution.

Comment: It depends more of the context, which is not provided in the question

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for variables is different in bash and in tcsh.

In tcs:

```
set var=val
```

In bash:

```
var=val
```

source just loads the shell script in your shell script, so the expected syntax is the one of the caller shell script.

Comment: I know they are different. I am better at bash. 
and even if I change my script to tcsh  I would just end up with the oppsitite problem if someone wants to run it from bash :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `source` your script, you have your current shell execute it, and the inital shebang is ignored. Since your current shell is `tcsh`, it expects tcsh syntax. If you want `bash` to execute your script, you should make it executable with a command like `chmod a+x my_tmp_script.sh`, then execute it directly:

```
./my_tmp_script.sh
```

Then, the initial shebang `#!/bin/bash` will be honoured and the right interpreter (`bash`) will be invoked.

Comment: This I had already tried, the problem with executing is that it is done in a different shell that is killed once the script is done. and the Variable is not set in the current shell

Comment: At this point, it would be much better that you give us a fuller context, in order that we understand what your problem really is and how to solve it in the best way. Please be as specific as possible, and state your _problem,_ not what you think the solution is.

Comment: @rasmus Are you still interested? Please tell us mote as I asked you in my comment above.

Comment: sorry it has been easter holidays in my country.
I think the main problem was (maybe still is) that I did not fully understand how the scripts are executed as you pointed out.

my final conclusion is there is no way of sourcing a bash script in a cshell process. 
I ended up converting my script to tsch...

Answer (score 0):

need to change your file like bellow

## !/bin/bash

## clear

echo $$

echo "setting environment variables"

setenv MY_TEMP_ENVVAR 123@tmp.com

echo $MY_TEMP_ENVVAR